# Como exportar os [[ ]] de uma lista em arquivos separados de excel usando o R?

Tags: r, exportação, split

Reproduzo aqui parte de um dataframe que estou trabalhando:

```
producao<-data.frame(
  discente = c("ANA",
               "ANA",
               "ANA",
               "ANA",
               "ANA",
               "MIGUEL",
               "MIGUEL",
               "MIGUEL",
               "MIGUEL",
               "MIGUEL",
               "JAIME",
               "JAIME",
               "JAIME",
               "JAIME",
               "JAIME",
               "JAIME",
               "JAIME",
               "SAULO",
               "SAULO"
  ),
  ano = c("2019",
          "2019",
          "2019",
          "2017",
          "2017",
          "2017",
          "2018",
          "2017",
          "2018",
          "2017",
          "2018",
          "2019",
          "2017",
          "2018",
          "2017",
          "2017",
          "2017",
          "2017",
          "2018"
  ),
  titulo = c("ABERTURA DO PROJETO UFPE NO MEU QUINTAL",
             "ACUMULAÇÃO POR DESPOSSESSÃO VISTA CARTOGRAFICAMENTE: Comunidade do Pilar",
             "ANÁLISE DA AUSÊNCIA DE INFORMAÇÃO EM PRODUTO MDE DO LIDAR NA INTERFACE ÁGUA/SOLO",
             "ANÁLISE DA CONTRIBUIÇÃO DA FUSÃO PELO MÉTODO IHS DE IMAGENS CBERS-2B (CCD E HRC) PARA DETECÇÃO DE BORDAS",
             "ANÁLISE DA EXTRAÇÃO DE LAGO POR MORFOLOGIA MATEMÁTICA EM IMAGEM IKONOS-2 E POR EXTRAÇÃO MANUAL",
             "ANÁLISE DA QUALIDADE AMBIENTAL NO RESERVATÓRIO SOBRADINHO, BRASIL, UTILIZANDO BIOINDICADORES E SENSORIAMENTO REMOTO",
             "ANÁLISE DAS ÁREAS CADASTRÁVEIS NA BASE DO SISTEMA NACIONAL DO CADASTRO AMBIENTAL RURAL (SICAR)",
             "ANÁLISE DAS BACIAS HIDROGRÁFICAS DO RIO BRÍGIDA, RIO TERRA NOVA E GRUPO DE BACIAS DE PEQUENOS RIOS",
             "ANÁLISE DE MÚLTIPLAS IMAGENS PARA DETECÇÃO DE BORDAS DO RESERVATÓRIO DE SOBRADINHO, BAHIA",
             "ANÁLISE ESPAÇO-TEMPORAL DA BARRAGEM BROTAS, ALTO CURSO DO RIO PAJEÚ - PE, MUNICÍPIO DE AFOGADOS DA INGAZEIRA",
             "ANÁLISE ESPAÇO-TEMPORAL DAS ÁREAS INUNDÁVEIS DO RESERVATÓRIO DE SOBRADINHO NA BACIA HIDROGRÁFICA DO RIO SÃO FRANCISCO RECIFE",
             "ANÁLISE ESPAÇO-TEMPORAL DE INCIDENTES COM TUBARÕES NO LITORAL DE PERNAMBUCO Dissertação",
             "ANÁLISE TEMPORAL A PARTIR DO MAPEAMENTO REGIONAL DO SOLO E DECLIVIDADE DE 1995 E IMAGENS DE SENSORIAMENTO REMOTO DE 2014",
             "ANÁLISE TEMPORAL DO USO E COBERTURA DO SOLO NO BIOMA CAATINGA EM PERNAMBUCO UTILIZANDO O MAPBIOMAS",
             "ANALYSIS OF ERRORS IN THE DIGITAL ELEVATION MODEL - SRTM FOR THE SOBRADINHO RESERVOIR/BA",
             "APLICAÇÃO DE FORMAS NATURAIS NO TRATAMENTO DE EFLUENTES: O USO DAS PLANTAS NA DEPURAÇÃO DE PEQUENOS AMBIENTES HÍDRICOS",
             "APLICAÇÃO E ANÁLISE DAS TÉCNICAS DE FUSÃO IHS E COMPONENTES PRINCIPAIS EM IMAGENS DO SATÉLITE CBERS-2B MULTISSENSORES HRC/CCD",
             "AS GEOTECNOLOGIAS E O CONTROLE DO CHORUME: O USO DA GEOCIÊNCIA NA AQUISIÇÃO DE AMBIENTES ADEQUADOS PARA ATERROS SANITÁRIOS CONTROLADOS",
             "AVALIAÇÃO DO SENSORIAMENTO REMOTO TERMAL PARA MONITORAMENTO DE ATERROS SANITÁRIOS"
  )
)


> head(producao)
  discente  ano                                                                                                              titulo
1      ANA 2019                                                                             ABERTURA DO PROJETO UFPE NO MEU QUINTAL
2      ANA 2019                                            ACUMULAÇÃO POR DESPOSSESSÃO VISTA CARTOGRAFICAMENTE: Comunidade do Pilar
3      ANA 2019                                    ANÁLISE DA AUSÊNCIA DE INFORMAÇÃO EM PRODUTO MDE DO LIDAR NA INTERFACE ÁGUA/SOLO
4      ANA 2017            ANÁLISE DA CONTRIBUIÇÃO DA FUSÃO PELO MÉTODO IHS DE IMAGENS CBERS-2B (CCD E HRC) PARA DETECÇÃO DE BORDAS
5      ANA 2017                      ANÁLISE DA EXTRAÇÃO DE LAGO POR MORFOLOGIA MATEMÁTICA EM IMAGEM IKONOS-2 E POR EXTRAÇÃO MANUAL
6   MIGUEL 2017 ANÁLISE DA QUALIDADE AMBIENTAL NO RESERVATÓRIO SOBRADINHO, BRASIL, UTILIZANDO BIOINDICADORES E SENSORIAMENTO REMOTO
```

Meu propósito é obter tabelas de excel com a produção de cada discente.
Usando a função `subset()` fica muito moroso, pois o dataset original tem 14 discentes. Então eu teria que ir digitando `subset(producao, producao$discente == "NOME DO DISCENTE")` para obter a produção de cada um e, depois, ainda teria que repetir 14 vezes o processo de exportação para excel.

Andei pesquisando e vi que é possível criar uma lista com a função `split()`

```
producao_per_discente<-split(producao, producao$discente)

$ANA
  discente  ano                                                                                                   titulo
1      ANA 2019                                                                  ABERTURA DO PROJETO UFPE NO MEU QUINTAL
2      ANA 2019                                 ACUMULAÇÃO POR DESPOSSESSÃO VISTA CARTOGRAFICAMENTE: Comunidade do Pilar
3      ANA 2019                         ANÁLISE DA AUSÊNCIA DE INFORMAÇÃO EM PRODUTO MDE DO LIDAR NA INTERFACE ÁGUA/SOLO
4      ANA 2017 ANÁLISE DA CONTRIBUIÇÃO DA FUSÃO PELO MÉTODO IHS DE IMAGENS CBERS-2B (CCD E HRC) PARA DETECÇÃO DE BORDAS
5      ANA 2017           ANÁLISE DA EXTRAÇÃO DE LAGO POR MORFOLOGIA MATEMÁTICA EM IMAGEM IKONOS-2 E POR EXTRAÇÃO MANUAL

$JAIME
   discente  ano                                                                                                                        titulo
11    JAIME 2018  ANÁLISE ESPAÇO-TEMPORAL DAS ÁREAS INUNDÁVEIS DO RESERVATÓRIO DE SOBRADINHO NA BACIA HIDROGRÁFICA DO RIO SÃO FRANCISCO RECIFE
12    JAIME 2019                                       ANÁLISE ESPAÇO-TEMPORAL DE INCIDENTES COM TUBARÕES NO LITORAL DE PERNAMBUCO Dissertação
13    JAIME 2017      ANÁLISE TEMPORAL A PARTIR DO MAPEAMENTO REGIONAL DO SOLO E DECLIVIDADE DE 1995 E IMAGENS DE SENSORIAMENTO REMOTO DE 2014
14    JAIME 2018                            ANÁLISE TEMPORAL DO USO E COBERTURA DO SOLO NO BIOMA CAATINGA EM PERNAMBUCO UTILIZANDO O MAPBIOMAS
15    JAIME 2017                                      ANALYSIS OF ERRORS IN THE DIGITAL ELEVATION MODEL - SRTM FOR THE SOBRADINHO RESERVOIR/BA
16    JAIME 2017        APLICAÇÃO DE FORMAS NATURAIS NO TRATAMENTO DE EFLUENTES: O USO DAS PLANTAS NA DEPURAÇÃO DE PEQUENOS AMBIENTES HÍDRICOS
17    JAIME 2017 APLICAÇÃO E ANÁLISE DAS TÉCNICAS DE FUSÃO IHS E COMPONENTES PRINCIPAIS EM IMAGENS DO SATÉLITE CBERS-2B MULTISSENSORES HRC/CCD

$MIGUEL
   discente  ano                                                                                                              titulo
6    MIGUEL 2017 ANÁLISE DA QUALIDADE AMBIENTAL NO RESERVATÓRIO SOBRADINHO, BRASIL, UTILIZANDO BIOINDICADORES E SENSORIAMENTO REMOTO
7    MIGUEL 2018                      ANÁLISE DAS ÁREAS CADASTRÁVEIS NA BASE DO SISTEMA NACIONAL DO CADASTRO AMBIENTAL RURAL (SICAR)
8    MIGUEL 2017                  ANÁLISE DAS BACIAS HIDROGRÁFICAS DO RIO BRÍGIDA, RIO TERRA NOVA E GRUPO DE BACIAS DE PEQUENOS RIOS
9    MIGUEL 2018                           ANÁLISE DE MÚLTIPLAS IMAGENS PARA DETECÇÃO DE BORDAS DO RESERVATÓRIO DE SOBRADINHO, BAHIA
10   MIGUEL 2017        ANÁLISE ESPAÇO-TEMPORAL DA BARRAGEM BROTAS, ALTO CURSO DO RIO PAJEÚ - PE, MUNICÍPIO DE AFOGADOS DA INGAZEIRA

$SAULO
   discente  ano
18    SAULO 2017
19    SAULO 2018
                                                                                                                                   titulo
18 AS GEOTECNOLOGIAS E O CONTROLE DO CHORUME: O USO DA GEOCIÊNCIA NA AQUISIÇÃO DE AMBIENTES ADEQUADOS PARA ATERROS SANITÁRIOS CONTROLADOS
19                                                      AVALIAÇÃO DO SENSORIAMENTO REMOTO TERMAL PARA MONITORAMENTO DE ATERROS SANITÁRIOS
```

Mas também só consigo chegar até aqui. Meu objetivo, de obter arquivos em excel para cada um dos `[[]]` da lista não é alcançado.

Em outras palavras, o que eu gostaria de saber é se existe a possibilidade de, com um comando, exportar a minha lista de modo que cada um `[[]]` se transforme em arquivos separados.
No exemplo em tela, seriam gerados 4 arquivos em excel.

Comment: Porque não um só arquivo com uma folha para cada lista?

Comment: Oi Rui; boa tarde. É porque preciso enviar os arquivos para cada um dos autores para eles conferirem se está tudo correto. Mas, só por curiosidade, como faria para colocar cada autor em uma folha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...

library(xlsx)

producao_per_discente<-split(producao, producao$discente)

lapply(seq_along(producao_per_discente), 
       function(i) write.xlsx(producao_per_discente[[i]],
                              file = paste0(names(producao_per_discente)[[i]],'.xlsx')))
```

Utilizei o pacote xlsx para gravar os arquivos.
O split produz uma lista de dataframes, utilizei o lapply para percorrer a lista, pegando o nome para salvar o xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui estão três modos diferentes, com três pacotes diferentes, de exportar uma lista de data.frames para um ficheiro Excel `".xlsx"` com cada data.frame em uma folha.

A lista é a da pergunta. O `split` cria uma lista com nomes e esses nomes vão ser os nomes das várias folhas. Os ficheiros têm os nomes "producao_per_discente_*n*.xlsx", *n* = 1, 2, 3.

```
producao_per_discente <- split(producao, producao$discente)
```

---

```
library(WriteXLS)

WriteXLS(producao_per_discente,
         ExcelFileName = "producao_per_discente_1.xlsx")
```

---

```
library(writexl)

write_xlsx(producao_per_discente,
           path = "producao_per_discente_2.xlsx")
```

---

```
library(xlsx)

for(i in seq_along(producao_per_discente)){
  write.xlsx(producao_per_discente[[i]], file = "producao_per_discente_3.xlsx",
             sheetName = names(producao_per_discente)[i], append = i > 1L)
}
```